# How to filter inner array ids on a second dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

I need to show rows from List 1 which has an inner array that contains reference IDs to a second list.

I've tried seperating the inner array to a standalone dataset, but I struggle with extracting the data.

DataSet 1:

```
scala> wayIds.printSchema
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- nd: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _ref: long (nullable = true) <-- THIS IS THE REFERENCE ID
```

DataSet 2:

```
scala> nodeIds.printSchema
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
```

The result would look something like this:

```
+----------+                                                                    
|       _id|
+----------+
| 253082104|
| 458193936|
| 721744820|
| 747193766|
+----------+
```

A list showing all IDs which has a reference to DataSet2._id

Comment: you can try to get array of _ref values and then use `explode` function on it, it will create one column df that you can join to second df

Comment: Thanks for comment. I think the solution I found is similar of what you are saying.

I renamed "_id" in nodeIds, to "ref", then I joined this column on the exploded "nd._ref" column in wayIds.